# AWS Lambda with Layers: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' Python 3.7 runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have deployed my **AWS lambda with layers**, installed all dependent modules in layers.

Following is the uploaded layer zip contents:
[image]

Still getting following **exception** while running lambda:

> Unable to import module 'handler': cannot import name '_imaging' from
> 'PIL' (/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/**init**.py)

**Lambda Snippet:**

```
import json

from PIL import Image 
 
def ocr(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

I am using ubuntu machine to generate Lambda layer and deploying it over AWS using aws deploy command.

**Tried updating Local Machine Python version to 3.7.9. still not working.**

Any suggestions would help me alot.. Thanks :)